# Redirection methods for webpages

Tags: url, cookies, redirect

(This is question involving user experience, but I am primarily interested in the best practice technical solution to this common problem.)

---

There are several places in my website where users are redirected: login screens, pay walls, etc.

Sometimes these can be stacked. For example, login, then pay, then land on a particular page. (But I can't just hardcode them...sometimes they would login, pay, and the go to another page.)

And the flow for users is dynamic, e.g. perhaps during the login flow the user may start an OAuth flow.

---

I can keep a "stack" of redirects.

I could chain the redirects in the URL:

```
http://my.website.com/login?return_url=%2Fpay%3Freturn_url%3D%252FfinalUrl
```

or I could keep track of them in a cookie (e.g. serialized JSON array).

---

Is one of these two ways that is better of keeping track of redirects, or is one of these ways commonly used?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by keeping a "track" of these URIs. Do you need to keep a track of what the user visited as a log, or do you need to keep all the URIs somewhere to which the user can go?

Comment: I need to keep track on the user's browser which URLs they need to be go to. A stack of redirects.